# React Native: print json data with react-native-bluetooch-escpos-printer plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a json data Request from Fetch MySql Table From Web API like this

```
[
    {"goods":"Avocado","amount":"4","price":"5000"},
    {"goods":"Pineapple","amount":"3","price":"3000"},
    {"goods":"Banana","amount":"9","price":"8500"},
]
```

by using the DataShow class structure below accompanied by the FlatList component, I can display it on an android screen like this

```
    Goods       Amount      Price
    Avocado        4        5.000
    Pineapple      3        3.000
    Banana         9        8.500
    TOTAL                  16.500
```

I want to print it via a *Bluetooth thermal printer as a receipt* so I use the plugin for *Bluetooth ESC / POS* printers. Print test with **await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("Test print \ r \ n", {})** command was successful, but I had difficulties entering the command in my DataShow class below with json data where ***the length of the json data can vary***. 
Can anyone help me ... thank you

```
class DataShow extends React.Component {
    ....
    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        data={this.props.navigation.state.params.datasource}
        return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View>
                 ????  how is the command to print the json data here
            </View>
        </View>
    }
}
```